# undefined is not an object (evaluating _react.default.PropTypes.func)

Tags: react-native, react-proptypes

I have been referring a tutorial having 8 sections since a week, on which the code base depends from section 1. On the later section, I had created a ColorForm.js file as per the tutorial which includes the below code. When I have defined the ColorForm.PropTypes such as

```
ColorForm.propTypes = {
    onNewColor: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

the app thrown an error, **undefined is not an object (evaluating _react.default.PropTypes.func)**

On referring various post I came to know that I had to install 'prop-types', even though I am getting the above error. Can anyone help me to sort out this issue. Thanks in advance.

ColorForm.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TextInput
} from 'react-native'

export default class ColorForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            txtColor: ''
        }

        this.props.onNewColor(this.state.txtColor.toLowerCase())
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this)
    }

    submit() {
        this.setState({txtColor: ''})
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style = {styles.container}>
                <TextInput 
                    style = {styles.txtInput}
                    placeholder = "Enter a color..."
                    onChangeText={(txtColor) => this.setState({txtColor})}
                    value  = {this.state.txtColor}
                />
                <Text style = {styles.button} onPress={this.submit}>Add</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

ColorForm.propTypes = {
    onNewColor: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
        height: 70
    },
    txtInput: {
        flex: 1,
        margin: 5,
        padding: 5,
        borderWidth: 2,
        fontSize: 20,
        borderRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'snow'
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: 'darkblue',
        margin: 5,
        padding: 5,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 20
    }
})
```

Comment: You didn't import prototypes.

Comment: import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with React.PropTypes.func.isRequired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697963/issue-with-react-proptypes-func-isrequired)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insted of React.PropTypes use PropTypes directly.

step 1 : `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

```
 onNewColor: PropTypes.func.isRequired
```

step 2.

```
 constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            txtColor: ''
        }

        this.props.onNewColor = this.onNewColor.bind(this)
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this)
    }

    onNewColor(textColor) => {
      return textColor.toLowerCase()
    }
```

step 3 :

```
  <TextInput 
      style = {styles.txtInput}
      placeholder = "Enter a color..."
      onChangeText={(txtColor) => this.setState({txtColor})}
      value  = {this.props.onNewColor(this.state.txtColor)}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. I modified it as you suggested, but now I am getting different error such as "undefined is not an object (evaluating _this.props.onNewColor)". Can you let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @sree_iphonedev is `this.props.onNewColor` defined? Can you please check if it's passed correctly?