# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.default.PropTypes.string')

Tags: react-native

im just creating a simple form with textinput and select .. Here is the code and when ever i'm trying to click on the input field its not showing the keypad. i don't understand what is the issue here , please help me to fix it
i'm new to react-native thanks in advance

```
 import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
 import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
 import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
 import { NavigationBar } from 'navigationbar-react-native';
 import  { Select, Option } from 'react-native-option-select';



class customer extends Component {

 render() {
  return (
     <View style = {styles.container}>
        <TextInput style = {styles.input}
           className="form-control"
           Type = "outlined"
           placeholder = "Enter Your Name"
           autoCapitalize = "none"
           onChangeText = {this.handleEmail}/>
        <TextInput style = {styles.input}
           className="form-control"
           Type = "outlined"
           placeholder = "Enter Your Email(optional)"
           autoCapitalize = "none"/>
        <Select
           width={250}
           defaultValue="Select a Province in Canada ...">
        <Option value = {{id : "alberta"}}>Alberta</Option>
        <Option>British Columbia</Option>
      </Select>
     <TouchableOpacity
        style = {styles.submitButton}
        onPress = {
           () => this.login()
        }>
        <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}> Connect </Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
  )
  }
 }
 export default customer
  Component.propTypes = {
   text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
 };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined is not an object (evaluating \_react.default.PropTypes.func)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59751362/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-react-default-proptypes-func)

Comment: yes, i already pass props but still showing the same issue